# Vagrant up builds suddenly new box and doesn't recognize old one

Tags: vagrant

We are using vagrant and puppet for setting up our test environments, this works reasonably. But sometimes there is a strange quirk. After someone has built a new box and used it for some time, a vagrant up suddenly ignores the existing box and creates a new one.

This is rather annoying, because the box is actually fine. How can I reassign the old box to my vagrant file again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That can happen sometimes when VirtualBox fails to report information about the machine. New Vagrant versions try to fetch it multiple times, but I guess this is still possible.

The mapping is done in the `.vagrant` directory of the project. For example with normal single-VM setup the UUID of the machine is stored in `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id`. You can get the list of existing VirtualBox VMs with `VBoxManage list vms`.

Comment: Which version is this? I have version 1.4.2, which makes an map vagrant.d with a different topology.

Comment: Vagrant 1.1 and forward. But not `~/.vagrant.d`, but `.vagrant` in the same directory where the Vagrantfile is.

Answer (score 0):

I found this happens when you change an unnamed configuration into a named configuration in your Vagrantfile. For example if you change your VagrantFile from

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant/install.sh"
end
```

to

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define "dev" do |dev|
    dev.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant/install.sh"
  end
end
```

and then `vagrant reload`, vagrant will lose track of the fact the the previously unnamed configuration is now named `dev`, and will treat `dev` as an entirely new VM (even though it is also the default, and only, VM in the Vagrantfile).

You can either:

- destroy the old VM manually (e.g. by opening up VirtualBox and deleting it); or
- change your Vagrantfile back, `vagrant destroy`, then roll the Vagrantfile forward and `vagrant up`.